# VueJS - NuxtJS - Auth Module - $router.push

Tags: javascript, vue.js, login, auth

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de practica que incluye un login. El tema esta en que la consulta a la api sobre el login lo hace bien, una vez que verifica eso, ya lo redirecciona a la pagina de inicio. Pero ese es el problema, no lo lleva a la pagina de inicio. En la consola de desarrollo de google, en la parte de Network se carga la pagina de inicio (index.js) pero no la muestra, se queda en el login.

Sinceramente no se donde esta el problema, si en el "this.$router.push('/')" o en el Auth module, la verdad no se, me estoy volviendo loco jaja.

***Login.vue***

```
  login() {
    if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
      this.$auth.loginWith('local', {params: {username: this.form.user, password: this.form.password}})
        .then(res => {
          // this.$toast.success('Ingreso con éxito');
          // this.$store.commit('sessionExpired/sessionExpired', false);
          this.$router.push('/');
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          this.$toast.error('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos')
      })
    }
  },
```

***nuxt.config.js***

```
      auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/auth/login', method: 'get', propertyName: 'token'
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/auth/logout', method: 'get'
          },
          user: {
            url: '/auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'token'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      home: '/',
      callback: '/login'
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono agregando la línea watchLoggedIn: false y quitando el callback ya que tenía el mismo error, solo que el push que hacía era hacía la página anterior o de origen, te anexo mi configuración

```
auth: {
strategies: {
  local: {
    endpoints: {
      login: {
        url: `${apiUrl}/auth/local`,
        method: 'post',
        propertyName: 'jwt',
      },
      logout: false,
      user: false,
    },
    tokenRequired: true,
    tokenType: 'bearer',
    tokenName: 'Authorization',
  },
},
redirect: {
  login: '/login',
  logout: '/',
  home: '/',
},
watchLoggedIn: false,
 },
```

Comment: en esta comunidad, se aprecian mucho mejor los códigos, cuando se explican el porque sugieres esta solución. Desconozco si la propuesta es buena o no encaja con lo que requiere el solicitante, pero para no recibir votos negativos, y que cierren la misma, perdiendo así el aporte que das, es el mejor camino.